# Why is my string variable not working when I try to combine it with other strings inside a loop?

Tags: python, scope

I have problem with my code, maybe a scope issue, but not sure.
I have a list of objects with a key "systems", that has subkeys that are the names of the systems with further key/values.
I can use the variable in the loop, can print it or assign it to another variable. But when I try to combine the variable with other strings it fails.
I have already checked the variable type with print type() and I get string back.

```
def get_systems(a_objects):
     for a in a_objects:
        name = (a['name'])
        if 'systems' in a:
            for sys in a['systems']:
                print name               # This works and prints the name
                print name + '-' + (sys) # This does not work and prints only the '-' and the sys
    return
```

Comment: you getting any runtime error ?

Comment: No, just the name string is missing

Answer (score 0):

When I printed each element of the list I did not notice, but when I printed the full list I noticed that every element had a '\r' at the end. That made it impossible to combine with any other string.
A simple .strip() in the code that extracted each string with a regex removed the carriage return and problem was fixed.